# SUM in stored procedure

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate the `SUM` of `MEMDISC` but I keep getting this error on a stored procedure

> Column 'dbo.ZZ.CNUM is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is my code

```
select
    CNUM, 
    DESCRIPT, 
    ZCONTDESC,
    substring(str(OCCDATE),9,2) + '/'+ substring(str(OCCDATE),7,2) + '/' + substring(str(OCCDATE),3,4),
    COWNNUM,
    CAST((CAST(substring(str(ANVDATE),3,4) AS INT) -1) AS CHAR(4))+'-' +substring(str(ANVDATE),3,4),
    sum(MEMDISC)
from 
    dbo.ZZ
```

What it should look like?

Comment: When you have any aggregate function (SUM, AVG, MIN and MAX) , you must use the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Looks like you need more SQL education.  And it helps to add which type of database you use.  Since there are no backticks, it's probably not MySQL. And no double pipes so probably not Oracle either.  MS SQL-Server?  Anyway, Like Lucky said. Since you use an aggregate function like SUM, you need to add a group by. Or remove the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments by @Lucky and @LukStorms, when you use aggregation functions you need to `GROUP BY` all fields which are not included in an aggregation function. In your case you need something like this:

```
select CNUM, DESCRIPT, ZCONTDESC,
   substring(str(OCCDATE),9,2) + '/'+ substring(str(OCCDATE),7,2) + '/' + substring(str(OCCDATE),3,4),
   COWNNUM,
   CAST((CAST(substring(str(ANVDATE),3,4) AS INT) -1) AS CHAR(4))+'-' +substring(str(ANVDATE),3,4),
   sum(MEMDISC)
  from dbo.ZZ
 group by CNUM, DESCRIPT, ZCONTDESC,
   substring(str(OCCDATE),9,2) + '/'+ substring(str(OCCDATE),7,2) + '/' + substring(str(OCCDATE),3,4),
   COWNNUM,
   CAST((CAST(substring(str(ANVDATE),3,4) AS INT) -1) AS CHAR(4))+'-' +substring(str(ANVDATE),3,4),
```

Comment: Thank You for your time. I've now understood how sum () Works!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.